# How to extends %module_x/templates/xyz.html.twig?

Tags: 8, theming

My module has a template which would like to extend another module's template. Is there any shortcut like we have in Symfony2?

```
{% extends 'path_to_module_x:templates/template-x.html.twig' %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An updated version of [@Cottser](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1554/cottser) answers is going to be like this....

```
 {% extends "node.html.twig" %}
```

This is been supported since this issue is been solve - https://www.drupal.org/node/2291449

Answer (score 4):

As of https://drupal.org/node/2143557 (committed January 24, 2014) you can now do this:

```
{% extends "@node/node.html.twig" %}
```

Note that the 'templates' directory is automatically included.